# Could a language be designed that does not require the escaping of quotes in string literals?

Tags: compiler-construction, language-agnostic, escaping, quotes, language-design

In C++ (and, after translation, most languages) the following is of course a syntax error:

```
std::string str = "Hello "Jesus""; // oopsquotes
```

Could a C++-like language be created that doesn't need these quotes escaping? Could a compiler see a line like the above and intelligently determine that I didn't want the string to terminate after `Hello`, *in the general case*?

Languages and compilers like to require us to write precise syntax to avoid ambiguities, but I can't seem to think up a non-contrived example similar to the above where the meaning could be anything but "please put `Hello "Jesus"` in a string". In C++, "Jesus" would have to be a preprocessor macro that expanded to some string literal `"x"`, for the above to potentially mean anything else. Is it very important to support this potential case in code where no such expansion exists?

So, could a language be created where we didn't need to escape quotes in a string literal? Can you think of any non-contrived counter-examples? *Should* a language like this exist? Perhaps one already does...?

Discuss.

Comment: I don't see why it'd be impossible, but I think this definatly comes under the heading of "resources best spent elsewhere".

Comment: @Tyler: It comes under the heading of "it's 1.30am, I'm on Stack Overflow, and I would like to broaden my horizons and those of my co-conspirators."

Comment: I meant that from a language designer standpoint: E.g. I've got 1000 things to add to my language that are more important than a corner case in string literals. PS, many languages DO have a way of doing this, e.g. triple quotes(""") in python.

Comment: @Tyler Eaves, I wouldn't put this on the bottom of 1000 things to add.  Embedded quotes are extremely common and having nice solutions helps.  Luckily there are many examples from existing languages that have alternative solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is relatively easy to implement in a PEG-based parser, utilising its infinite lookahead capability. But, as the others already mentioned, there is no point in doing it, as it won't always be possible to resolve the ambiguities, especially in cases when you want to embed a well-formed code into a string. It might be somewhat easier if you disallow multi-line strings.

Comment: +1 for naming one of the cases of ambiguity, in particular. That's a good example of where even a human might fail to parse the code as expected.

Answer (score -1):

in Python you can do `str = 'Hello "Jesus"'` without problem or `str = """Hello "Jesus"."""`

Comment: That's not relevant. You've used explicit syntax to identify the delimiters from the embedded string. I'm talking about a hypothetical language that doesn't need this.

Comment: What would be the benefit of that over the alternate quoting I used here? Even for us it would be more complicated to read, not speaking of the extra work for the compiler.

Comment: I don't know. The point of this question is to find out what people think about it.

Comment: @Tomalak - Ok, I understood, thanks. Probably should be better as a community question as there are no wright or wrong answers but my opinion is that it's far from being a priority point and I'm not sure it would be better than what we have available now in some languages.

Comment: I agree; it would be best as a community question. It's my intention to make it one at some point.

Answer (score -1):

Some languages use different types of quotes, thus making it possible to have quotes of different types in string literals. For instance, Python has this with double quotes, single quotes and three double quotes.

Bash has some form of "user-customizable" quoting mechanism:

```
cat <<EOF
Hello "World"
EOF
```

I like that, because in cases where your string literal contains EOF, you can just choose to use something else for the "end of quote" delimiter.

Comment: Indeed, though I'm talking about a hypothetical language that can resolve ambiguity of quotes-inside-quotes using whatever clever logic the human brain uses, rather than taking the quotes out of the equation altogether.

Comment: I think my text answers the title of your question ("yes, it is possible"). Regarding the additional information in the details of the question, my guess is that this is not possible. String literals containing code would almost certainly lead to ambiguous interpretations, even for humans. Consider e.g. `print "" print ""`.

Comment: "Could a C++-like language be created that doesn't need these quotes escaping" refers specifically to the example given, where quotes are still used to delimit the string. Sorry for the confusion.